# Unity checkReleaseDuplicateClasses Failed

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I know this is a known issue on multiple librarys using diferent versions of the same resource, but I'm with no clue of what gone wrong in the imports. I'm using firebase with unity, targeting android 34, and I'm getting this error:

> Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache found in modules jetified-androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.3.1.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.3.1.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)

The app is working fine on the emulator, this error is in the build.
I have custom main gradle template and properties. Heres my gradle file:

```
// Android Resolver Repos Start ([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:20, Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:24, Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:20
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7, Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    } } // Android Resolver Repos End apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.3.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0' // Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.core/Editor/Dependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0' // Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.review/Editor/Dependencies.xml:3
    //implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:2.1.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleUmpDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:11.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:11.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-unity:11.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AuthDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.3.3' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-unity:11.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/DatabaseDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:11.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:24
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-unity:11.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/StorageDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:1.12.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/MessagingDependencies.xml:19 // Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
    } }

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start android {   packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')   } } // Android Resolver Exclusions End android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = **BUILTIN_NOCOMPRESS** + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS** }**REPOSITORIES** **IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP** **SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP** **EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

If anyone has any clue about what went wrong, please tell me.

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

And

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
```

are some tries from another stackoverflow aswers about similar situations...

Comment: Do you use google-jar-resolver(External Dependency Manager) or any other plugin for jar packages resolving?

Comment: yes, I've run android resolver several times

Comment: I update some packages and now i'm getting "  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class _COROUTINE.ArtificialStackFrames found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.3.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.3.jar) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.3.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.7.3)"...

Answer (score 0):

In looks like you have unnecessary `*.jar` files in your `Plugins/Android` folder. Probably, something went wrong with your package resolver cache, or you added some jars manually, that led to the dependencies inconsistency. Try to remove `*jar` files, which cause exceptions from your project. The required ones still will be downloaded with gradle `implementation` scheme.